# Inner Join with multiple list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, linq

I have some question about the inner join for the multiple list.
First I have ViewModel called AdminSettingsModel

```
    public partial class AdminSettingsModal
{
   public List<ReportTypes> reportTypes { get; set; }
   public List<UserType> userType { get; set; }     

}

    public partial class ReportTypes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public int? UserType { get; set; }
    public string IconPath { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public int GotSop { get; set; }
    public int ThirdParty { get; set; }
}

    public partial class UserType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Access { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to return userType and Reporttype(need inner join with userType)  in the controller.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        AdminSettingsModal admin = new AdminSettingsModal();
        admin.userType = await _context.UserType.ToListAsync();
        admin.reportTypes = await _context.ReportTypes.ToListAsync();

        return View(admin);
    }
```

1. Any idea or how should I do if want to use inner join method for example the sql is like this

SELECT reportTypes.Id, reportTypes.ReportName, userType.Type
FROM reportTypes
INNER JOIN userType
ON reportTypes.UserType = userType.Id;

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your SQL query

```
SELECT reportTypes.Id, reportTypes.ReportName, userType.Type FROM reportTypes 
INNER JOIN userType ON reportTypes.UserType = userType.Id;
```

> Create one model class for report

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ReportName {get;set;}
    public int Type {get;set;}
}
```

> Inner join query

```
var oJoinData = from userType in _context.UserType 
JOIN ReportTypes in _context.ReportTypes ON
userType.Id = ReportTypes.UserType
select new ReportModel 
{
    Id = userType.Id,ReportName=ReportTypes.ReportName,Type = reportTypes.UserType
}
```